# TYPO3 Crawler is loading till internal server error 500 comes up

Tags: web-crawler, typo3

I configured the crawler (Version 5.1.3) on multiple TYPO3 instances (the Configuration and the TYPO3 Version [7.6.20] are always the same). Sometimes its working and sometimes I have this problem:

After all the [Configurations](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html) are made I want to start crawling in Web --> Info --> Site Crawler --> Start Crawling.
When i select a page in the pagetree and klick on: [image] then it is loading 10 - 15 minutes and i get a Server Error (500).

This makes it impossible to use the crawler to crawl pages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check your log in backend there you can find true error

Comment: There is nothing related to this issue in the Backend logs.

Comment: is "curl"  is  allowed in your localconfiguration .php file ?

Comment: The Localconfiguration - Files are all configured the same way in every TYPO3 Instance that i've used. There is nothing configured in relation to curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I have to use the CGI Version of PHP (In this case 7.0.20)